# Trouble implementing backgroundworker in a function

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

Everything I read points me to the need to run my "CollectSample" function in a backgroundworker1 but using all the samples I can't figure it out or compile. Because I am very new to vb, and not a strong programmer, I can't figure out how to invoke, or use background worker in the following code. A quick summary, I am calling realterm as a process and it opens and closes just fine, but locks out win form and because its in a loop of 16, I can't breakout if needed? Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub Button35_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button35.Click

    ProgressBar2.Visible = True
    ProgressBar2.Value = 0

    For i As Integer = 17 To 32
        DirectCast(Me.Controls.Find("Button" & i, True)(0), Button).Visible = False
    Next

    For Bindex = 17 To 32

        Dim Counter As Integer = 0
        Dim Tone As Integer = TextBox1.Text
        Dim Duration As Integer = TextBox2.Text

        Duration = Duration * 2
        For Counter = 1 To Duration
            Counter = Counter + 1
            NtBeep(Tone, 200)  'f,d
        Next

        CollectSample("SAMPLE" & Bindex - 16 & ".txt")  'subtracting the first 16
        ProgressBar2.PerformStep()
        CheckSample("SAMPLE" & Bindex - 16 & ".txt")

        DirectCast(Me.Controls.Find("Label" & Bindex, True)(0), Label).Visible = True
        DirectCast(Me.Controls.Find("Button" & Bindex, True)(0), Button).Visible = True

        If SampleFlag = 1 Then  'error readiing from instument
            DirectCast(Me.Controls.Find("Label" & Bindex, True)(0), Label).Text = "Er00"
            DirectCast(Me.Controls.Find("Button" & Bindex, True)(0), Button).Text = "Er00"
        End If

        If SampleFlag = 2 Then  'sample count error
            DirectCast(Me.Controls.Find("Label" & Bindex, True)(0), Label).Text = IncSamp
            DirectCast(Me.Controls.Find("Button" & Bindex, True)(0), Button).Text = IncSamp
        End If

        If SampleFlag = 0 Then   'sample good
            If SendMyAvg <> 0 Then
                SendMyAvg = Math.Round(SendMyAvg, 2)
                '  MessageBox.Show("Button" & Bindex & " / " & SendMyAvg)
                DirectCast(Me.Controls.Find("Label" & Bindex, True)(0), Label).Text = SendMyAvg
                DirectCast(Me.Controls.Find("Button" & Bindex, True)(0), Button).Text = SendMyAvg
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub


Private Sub CollectSample(ByVal Samplefile As String)   'call realterm, close realterm
    NtBeep(500, 200)  'f,d
    'http://www.dotnetperls.com/process-vbnet
    Dim p As New ProcessStartInfo
    p.FileName = "C:\Program Files (x86)\BEL\Realterm\realterm.exe"
    p.Arguments = "C:\Program Files (x86)\BEL\Realterm\realterm.exe Baud=4800 Data=7E2 Port=" & USBPort & " timestamp=4 capfile=C:\IMAX_Ware_V2\LS100Cap\""" & targetName & """ capsecs=35 capture=1 Sendfile=""" & sourceName & """ Senddly=3000 Sendrep=10 CapQuit"

    p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    Dim myProcess As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(p)
    myProcess.WaitForExit()
    myProcess.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: Please fix your title to something descriptive: we know it is VB from the tag, and you really dont need to tell us you are a "noob".  Hard to tell what a Background worker has to do with the question, but you lost me at `On Error Resume Next`  *captain! we've struck an iceberg!!* cap: *very well, full steam ahead, and where's my bloody tea?*

Comment: The trick with threads, is that a seperate thread can't access controlls (i.e. progress bar, textbox, label, etc) on the UI form thread without being invoked.  I know it may seem pointless, but it's a way to keep things safe.  This link might help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: With a Background worker, your function becomes the `DoWork` method.  But you cant access UI controls from it (which the code seems very concerned with).